# BufferedReader.nextLine() will not advance to the next line so I'm stuck in a loop

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am trying to reuse input method for both `Scanner(System.in)` and `BufferedReader(FileReader)`. When the user types "readfile" as a command, the program adds the first person from the file (ie the first line from the file) to a list, but the `BufferedReader` is stuck on the same line and therefore is stuck in an infinite loop.
The `Scanner` method from keyboard input works like a charm.

```
    class Menu {
        public static final int ARRAYINDEXFOREMAIL = 3;
        private static final String NEWPERSON = "newperson";
        private static final String FROMFILE = "readfile";
        public static final String READFILE = "saved.txt";
        private Scanner keyboardInput = new Scanner( System.in );
        private String name;
        private String tlf;
        private String[] email;
        private String [] stringTmp;
        private String in;
        private boolean readFromFile = false;

        Menu( boolean fileRead ) {
            if( fileRead ) {
                readFromFile = true;
            }
            else {
                readFromFile = false;
            }
        }

        void run() {
            while(true) {
                System.out.print("\n" + "ordre> ");
                if ( !readFromFile ) {
                    in = keyboardInput.nextLine();
                }
                else {
                    try {
                        BufferedReader fileOut = new BufferedReader(
                                new FileReader( READFILE ) );
                        if( ( in = fileOut.readLine() ) == null ) {
                            readFromFile = false;
                            fileOut.close();
                            break;
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("in stringTmp is: " + in);   // For debugging purposes
                        }
                    }
                    catch (FileNotFoundException filenotfoundexception) {
                        System.out.println("Cannot find file: " + READFILE + " !");
                    }
                    catch (IOException ioexception) {
                        ioexception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                stringTmp = in.split("\\s+");

                if( stringTmp[0].equalsIgnoreCase(NEWPERSON) ) {
                    if( stringTmp.length <= 1 ) {
                        System.out.println("ERROR! Enter one or more parameters..");
                        continue;
                    }
                    else {
                        name = stringTmp[1];
                        tlf = stringTmp[2];
                        if( stringTmp.length > ARRAYINDEXFOREMAIL ) {
                            email = new String[stringTmp.length - ARRAYINDEXFOREMAIL];

                            for( int i = ARRAYINDEXFOREMAIL, j = i - ARRAYINDEXFOREMAIL ; i < stringTmp.length; i++, j++ ) {
                                email[j] = stringTmp[i];
                            }
                        }
                        else {
                            email = new String[0];
                        }
                        mainlist.addPerson( name, tlf, email );
                    }
                }

                else if ( stringTmp[0].equalsIgnoreCase(FROMFILE) ) {
                    Meny m = new Menu( true );
                    m.run();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that the line you read finishes with a return carriage?

Comment: Yes - The same program writes all the persons from the list to the file and appends "\n" to each line (I'm working in Linux). When I read the file in vim, it has linebreaks at the correct places.

Answer (score 7):

Note that in the loop itself you set

```
BufferedReader fileOut = new BufferedReader(new FileReader( READFILE ) );
```

This will cause a new `BufferedReader` to be created!

In the loop's next iteration - you will repeat this line, reset `fileOut` as a result - and when you invoke `fileOut.readLine()` - it will read the first line again.

You should initialize `fileOut` before the loop and not in it to solve it.

Comment: Sweet! But isn't the code more prone to errors if the opening and closing of the file is on different sides of a while loop?

Comment: You're supposed to use a try-finally block to ensure that your resources are always closed. In Java 7 you can use the new language construct try-with-resources and it will handle this for you. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: Also, what is making your code error prone is how long it is. If a method is longer than a screen you should separate things into multiple methods to make it easier to read.

Comment: This fix just opened up a new can of worms for me as I am not very proficient with catching exceptions. I have previously used the try/catch method for nothing other than file I/O and have copied them from the web with a vague understanding of how they work.  I tried to do as amit adviced so I moved the init of the BufferedReader before the while loop, and with the added input from Sarel Botha I inserted a finally block where I set the necessary variables and close the file. Now IOException is unreachable and FileNotFoundException is already caught.

Comment: @jollyroger If you have new problems is a different issue entirely then the one discussed in this thread. If you fail to solve these problems you should ask a new question, post the relevant new code, and explain the problem. I am sure someone will answer this question pretty fast.